# Flutter wizard not set up

Tags: flutter, dart, intellij-idea, wizard

I am trying to set up flutter so as to start writing basic codes. I have installed the dart and flutter plugin on intelli j IDEA and also Android studio. I have also downloaded the flutter sdk zip file and extracted into local disc C:/src/ and I have set the bin path on environment variable.
But I still cannot get the flutter wizard to come on both on intelli j and Android studio..(that is not the same for dart)..
While running flutter doctor on cmd I get the message found an existing pub cache at c:\user\HP\AppData\Local\pub\cache
Can be repaired by running dart pub cache repair/clear..
And when I type this on cmd..nothing obvious happens..please I need help.

I installed latest intelli j and Android sdk..and I manually configure the Android studio sdk by setting it's path directory.
I downloaded dart and flutter plugin and sdk(s) and I set path to environment variable..

I was expecting the flutter wizard to be set up both on intelli j and Android studio..but no change occurs.. even though it is indicated in plugin section that flutter plugin is installed

Comment: Could you please share idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after restarting IDE and screenshot from "New Project Wizard"?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: To make sure that all the needed plugins are enabled try to delete the `disabled_plugins.txt` file from the configuration directory: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#config-directory while the IDE is closed.